# How to add client_id to requests performed by Spring Boot OAuth Security for Twitch

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth

I am using Spring Security OAuth.  Spring is successfully able to exchange an authentication for an access token.

However, for subsequently accessing protected resources, Twitch also requires that the client_id is passed when accessing protected resources, and Spring seems to only be passing in the access_token.

I tried updating the template, as such, but this does not seem to pass them as additional URI parameters, either:

```
OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext());
HashMap map = new HashMap();
map.put("client_id", "MY_CLIENT_SECRET");
template.setDefaultUriVariables(map);
filter.setRestTemplate(template);
```

Again, that does not seem to work either.

How do I tell Spring's OAuth2 to also pass the client_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a custom UserInfoTokenService, and overriding getMap(String path, String accessToken):

```
        MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        DefaultOAuth2AccessToken token = new DefaultOAuth2AccessToken(
                accessToken);
        headers.add("Authorization", String.format("%s %s", "OAuth", accessToken));
        logger.info(String.format("%s %s", "OAuth", accessToken));
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        HttpEntity he = new HttpEntity(null, headers);
        ResponseEntity<Map> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(path, HttpMethod.GET, he,
                Map.class);
        return exchange.getBody();
```